# count rows based on the date section in a timestamp column

Tags: mysql

I have a table `food_orders` with the following schema:

```
ID    created_at
=========================
1   2017-08-31 20:49:47
2   2017-09-20 21:07:52
3   2017-09-23 21:07:52
4   2017-09-23 20:07:52
```

I need to count the number of orders made in a day for the last 10 days.
I need something like this:

```
Date           no_orders
=========================
2017-08-31      1
2017-09-20      1
2017-09-23      2
```

I tried:

```
SELECT created_at, COUNT('id') AS qty  FROM orders WHERE created_at > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY) group by created_at
```

which of course gave me all records with no_orders 1
Please help me guys!

Comment: Do you need the last 10 days or the last 80 days?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen of course 10 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a simple aggregation query.  The only caveat here is that your `created_at` column is a timestamp, so we need to cast it to a date to force all times in a given day onto the same date.

```
SELECT
    DATE(created_at) AS Date,
    COUNT(*) AS no_orders
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    created_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 10 DAY
GROUP BY
    DATE(created_at)
```

Comment: It's not so minor. On a large data set, the difference can be significant! Poaching's cool. ;-)

Comment: In a now deleted comment @strawberry had admonished me because initially I had `DATE(created_at)` in the `WHERE` clause of my answer.  This is not attractive because it would preclude the ability of MySQL using any index on the `created_at` column, and this could hurt performance.

Comment: 'Admonished' is a bit severe. I prefer to think of it as a friendly 'cajole'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(created_at AS DATE) AS createdDay, COUNT('id') AS qty  
FROM orders 
WHERE created_at > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 80 DAY) 
group by CAST(created_at AS DATE)
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/369307/1)

Results:

```
| createdDay | qty |
|------------|-----|
| 2017-08-31 |   1 |
| 2017-09-20 |   1 |
| 2017-09-23 |   2 |
```